# Why does User.first take more time to query the database for the first time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

When I open the console of an existing application and type in :

```
2.1.1 :001 > User.first
  User Load (17.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: xxxx .... >
```

typing the query next time :

```
2.1.1 :002 > User.first
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: xxxx .... >
```

You can see the difference between the time taken by rails to query the database. Is something like caching available in console. How does this behave in running applications. Does it more time or even it is cached, where exactly does it do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The database server caches queries in the query cache.

See here for documentation on the mysql database query cache:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html

ActiveRecord also performs query caching:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Both of these may be happening depending on your system configuration.

Comment: And lower level cache such as (in the case of mysql) innodb buffer pools etc, table definition caches etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using rails 4, the database connection is not established straight away, until you make a query so:

```
2.1.1 :001 > User
 => User(no database connection) 
2.1.1 :002 > User.first
User Load (28.8ms)
2.1.1 :003 > User.first
User Load (1.9ms)
2.1.1 :004 > User.last
User Load (2.8ms)
```

So the initial query is establishing a database connection. Those after are then using the cache (as mentioned in other answer) and already established connection.